# Show/hide DOM elements according to input range value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

I have an HTML DOM element with 4 children like this:

```
<div id="container>
    <img class="hide>
    <img class="hide>
    <img class="hide>
    <img class="hide>
</div>
```

And I have an input range element like this:

```
<input id="input_range type="range" min="1" max="4" value="1">
```

I want to show/hide the `img` elements according to the input range value.

For example: if the input value is currently 3, I want to show the 1st, 2nd and 3rd `img`, and hide the 4th `img` by toggling CSS classes.

How to do that with vanilla Javascript?

Here is my current script:

```
var input_range = document.getElementById('input_range');
var scene = document.getElementById('container');

input_range.addEventListener('input', function(){
    hideElements(container, this.value);
})

function hideElements(parent_element, number_of_children){
    var children = parent_element.children;
    for (left = 0; left < number_of_children; ++left) {
        children[left].classList.remove('hide');
    }

}
```

This code works for removing the CSS hide class. But how to put the class back according to the input value?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How does your script look like ?

Comment: I edited my first post and added my current script.

Comment: It would be good if you could add code as js snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work like this

```
var input_range = document.getElementById('input_range');
var scene = document.getElementById('container');

input_range.addEventListener('input', function(){
    hideElements(container, this.value);
})

function hideElements(parent_element, number_of_children){
    var children = parent_element.children;
    for (left = 0; left < children.length; ++left) {
        if (left < number_of_children) {
            children[left].classList.remove('hide');
        } else {
            children[left].classList.add('hide');
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using a custom prototype: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmbeWw

Please note, I've used divs instead just so I could display the output.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="input_range" type="range" min="1" max="4" value="1">
<div id="container">
  <div class="hide">1</div>
  <div class="hide">2</div>
  <div class="hide">3</div>
  <div class="hide">4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var input_range = document.getElementById('input_range');
var scene = document.getElementById('container');

input_range.addEventListener('input', function(){
  scene.elementRange(this.value, 'hide', 'show');
  scene.elementRange(this.value, 'show', 'hide');
});

Node.prototype.elementRange = function(range, newClass, oldClass){
  for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
    this.children[i].classList.add(oldClass);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < range; i++) {
    this.children[i].classList.remove(oldClass);
    this.children[i].classList.add(newClass);
  }
}
```